# ActionsContentView Library - Menu Item (Expand/ Collapse)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

Does ActionsContentView Library contain any methods for expanding and collapsing of parent menu item? For example a menu item can have many children. On tapping of the parent item, the child items will then be displayed.

Example: On tap of Countries, then Singapore, Taiwan and Australia will show up.

Countries
      Singapore
      Taiwan
      Australia

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be inflating the desired view on the menu items

// I did not test this just showing the concept

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(context_here).inflate(R.layout.the_layouttoinflate, null);
```